# Using a USB phone charger to power sensor bin (instead of batteries)

Tags: power, batteries, usb

I have one of those sensor bins that opens the lid automatically when you wave your hand near it. It needs 3 AA batteries. As it just sits in the kitchen near a power socket, I figured it would be better if I could just run it off the mains electrical supply instead of having to replace batteries from time to time.

Also, like a lot of people I guess, I have quite a number of old USB phone chargers knocking around. So, my thought process was:

1. phone chargers supply around 5V.
2. The AA batteries (x3) supply around 4.5V.

Therefore, it seems feasible that I could solder the 5V supply connectors to the appropriate terminals in battery holder on the unit, and run it off the mains.

I have a basic working knowledge electronics but am not an expert by any means. I would guess that 4.5V is near enough to 5V that it should be OK, but the other thing that concerns me is I don't know what sort of amperage I should ensure the power supply is capable of, and whether this could be an issue with typical phone chargers.

Does this sound like a feasible project for an novice. Any advice or encouragement/discouragement to try this?

Comment: (1) Have you got a multimeter? (2) Do you know how to take a voltage measurement and a current measurement?

Comment: You are right, you need to know the current rating of the USB supply (it's not really a *charger*) as well as the current requirements for the motor. We can't give you much advice without that information.

Comment: A simple approach to lower the voltage would be a single diode in series with the supply to lower the 5 volts to about 4.3V.